# Coin that lands in a plane tessellated by triangles..

Tags: probability, geometry

A coin of radius 1 cm is tossed onto a plane surface that has been tessellated by right triangles whose sides are 8 cm, 15 cm, and 17 cm long. Find the probability that the coin lands within a triangle.

I know that this has to do with similarity because the inner triangle that is formed by the area where the coin can land is similar to the outer triangle. Therefore, I know the angles of this triangle, but I am not sure how to find one side of this triangle.

Comment: more to the point, the center of the coin must lie within a little triangle for it not to cover part of the boundary. The area of the little triangle divided by the area of the big triangle is the probability.Draw some pictures.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

First since $I$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$, you can find $$IH={2S_{ABC}\over P_{ABC}}={120\over 40}={3}$$ where $S$ denotes area and $P$ denotes perimeter.

Next you find $$IM=IH-1=2$$

Notice $I$ is also the incenter of the inner triangle. Now you know the side ratio between the two triangles is $2\over 3$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compute the sides of the new triangle, you only need to know the change in the inradius.

Given any triangle with area $\Delta$ and perimeter $\ell$, its inradius $r$ equals to $\frac{2\Delta}{\ell}$.

If one parallel shift all three edges inwards for a small distance $\rho$, the shrinked triangle will be similar to original triangle, sharing same incenter and has inradius $r - \rho$. The area of the shrinked triangle is given by:

$$\Delta_{\rm shrink} = \Delta \left( 1 - \frac{\rho}{r}\right)^2 = \Delta\left(1 - \frac{\rho\ell}{2\Delta}\right)^2$$

For the problem at hand, the area and perimeter of a triangle tile are:
$$\Delta = \frac{8\cdot 15}{2} = 60\quad\text{ and }\quad \ell = 8+15+17 = 40$$

In order for the coin to falls completely inside the interior of a triangle tile, its center needs to lie inside a shrinked triangle of the tile obtained by a shift with $\rho = 1$. This means the probability for the coin to fall complete inside a tile is

$$\frac{\Delta_{\rm shrink}}{\Delta} = \left(1 - \frac{\rho\ell}{2\Delta}\right)^2 = \left(1 - \frac{1\cdot 40}{2\cdot 60}\right)^2 = \left(1 - \frac13\right)^2 = \frac{4}{9}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $O$ is the center of the coin, the locus of $O$ inside a single $8$-$15$-$17$ right triangle $\triangle ABC$ such that the coin does not intersect any of the sides, is another triangle, say $\triangle A'B'C'$, that is similar in shape.  Moreover, $\triangle A'B'C'$ shares the same *incenter* as $\triangle ABC$ because corresponding pairs of vertices, e.g. $A$ and $A'$, lie on the same angle bisectors.

Note that $$|\triangle ABC| = rs$$ where $r$ is the inradius and $s = (a+b+c)/2$ is the semiperimeter.  Similarly, $$|\triangle A'B'C'| = r's'$$ where $r' = r-1$ is the inradius of the smaller triangle.  And because of similarity, $s'/s = r'/r$; consequently $$\frac{|\triangle A'B'C'|}{|\triangle ABC|} = \frac{r's'}{rs} = \left(\frac{r'}{r}\right)^2 = \left(1 - \frac{1}{r}\right)^2.$$  Since $|\triangle ABC| = (8)(15)/2 = 60$ and $s = (8+15+17)/2 = 20$, we have $r = 3$ and the desired probability is $$(1 - 1/3)^2 = \frac{4}{9}.$$